# iOS7 strange issue. Recorder not stopped

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, iphone-5

i am developing one app in that app i have used the AudioRecorder. my recorder doesent stop when app is close. red status bar shows when my app is background.

used this code...

```
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                                   @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                                   nil];
        NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

        // Setup audio session
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        //[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

        [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

        // Define the recorder setting
        NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

        // Initiate and prepare the recorder
        delegate.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];

        delegate.recorder.delegate=self;

        delegate.recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [delegate.recorder prepareToRecord];


        //[recorder record];  // Do not start recording here

        [delegate.recorder updateMeters];
        level = [delegate.recorder peakPowerForChannel:0];

        //AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        //[audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];


        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2  target:self
                                               selector:@selector(updateAudioMeter)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];



-(void)updateAudioMeter
{
    AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    [delegate.recorder updateMeters];


    level = [delegate.recorder averagePowerForChannel:0];

    NSLog(@"%f",level);

    if(level<=-120)
    {
        [delegate.recorder record];
    }
    else
    {
        [delegate.recorder stop];
    }
}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [recorder stop];
}
```

but when my app is close the red status bar shows means my iPhone5 not stop the recording. where may i wrong please help me solve this.

Comment: do you close it or you really terminate it?

Comment: How are you handling the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` notification? Are you stopping the recorder there?

Comment: @neilco done this but not work. stop recorder in applicationDidEnterBackground: but not work. please help...

Comment: Show us your `applicationDidEnterBackground:` implementation.

Comment: @JitendraDeore "Did not work" is unhelpfully vague. Be specific with your responses. What exactly did not work? Show us your code.

Comment: my recorder not stop when app close still red status bar shows... for long time....

Comment: Does this happen if you're not running using Xcode?

Comment: How are you declaring the `recorder` variable that is used in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`?

Comment: declare property in AppDelegate.h file like this @property AVAudioRecorder *  recorder;

Comment: Is it indeed not declared as being `strong`?